# Proving the existence of a unique solution $u$ in Row A for $Au = Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove, as stated in the title, that there exists a unique solution $u$ in Row A for $Au = Ax$, where $x$ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have to admit that I am pretty stumped. My first thought was to see if defining $Au = A^Tz$ for some $z$ would help, so that the equation would look like $AA^Tu = Ax$ and I would have a symmetric matrix on the left-hand side to mess around with. I ended up realizing that I misunderstood some of the properties of symmetric matrices, however, so I'm back to square one.

$A$ is any $m$-by-$n$ matrix. $u$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Is $A$ a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Suzu Hirose: I don't believe so.

Comment: You haven't specified what anything in the question is, how can this be answered?

Comment: @SuzuHirose What would you like specified? Sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: What is Row A??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uniqueness, let $\boldsymbol{u}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{u}_2$ be two elements of the row space such that $A\boldsymbol{u}_1 = A\boldsymbol{u}_2 = A\boldsymbol{x}$. Then $A(\boldsymbol{u}_1 - \boldsymbol{u}_2) = A\boldsymbol{u}_1 - A\boldsymbol{u}_2 = 0$. Therefore $\boldsymbol{u}_1 - \boldsymbol{u}_2$ is in the null space of $A$. Since the row space of $A$ is a subspace, $\boldsymbol{u}_1 - \boldsymbol{u}_2$ is also in the row space of $A$. As the row space and null space are orthogonal complements, the only vector in both is the zero vector. Hence $\boldsymbol{u}_1 - \boldsymbol{u}_2 = 0$ and $\boldsymbol{u}_1 = \boldsymbol{u}_2$.

For existence, let $\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{u} + \boldsymbol{v}$ be the orthogonal decomposition of $\boldsymbol{x}$ into the sum of an element $\boldsymbol{u}$ in the row space and $\boldsymbol{v}$ in the null space. Then $A\boldsymbol{x} = A\boldsymbol{u} + A\boldsymbol{v} = A\boldsymbol{u} + 0 = A\boldsymbol{u}$.

Answer (score 0):

first, $u$ must be like $x$ a column vector of size $n \times 1.$ second, if you are trying to show $A$ is 1-1, then you show $Au = 0$ has only the trivial solution. you do this by row reducing(gaussian elimination) and show every row has a pivot (non zero leading number).

Comment: I am not trying to show that A is 1-1.